# Best publisher for books intended for graduate students

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

Just looking for some advice on the best publishing homes for books intended for graduate students in differential geometry/mathematical physics.

My collaborators and me are finishing a book and we do not really know where it's best for us to submit it. We are looking for free publishing + annual royalties.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: It is off-topic. Anyway, Springer is good one.